# Mime type missing for .rar and .tar

Tags: javascript, jquery, mime-types

Javascript (Windows 8.1, Firefox) doesn't seem to have mime types for .tar files or .rar files (and perhaps others; these are the only two I've found). What's up with that? Is there anything I can use to resolve this? I'd really like to be able to retrieve mime types for these file types without doing some weird extension hacking.

I made a fiddle to prove the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/kungfujoe/jd8h7wvs/

If you browse to a .txt, or a .docx, or so many other formats, the type is pulled successfully. However, both .tar and .rar don't pull them. Odd, right?

(JSFiddle code below)

HTML

```
<input id='button' type='file' name='file'/>
<div id='out'>Output Goes Here</div>
```

Javascript (using JQuery 2.1.0)

```
$('#button').unbind('change');
$('#button').bind('change', function () {
    if(this.files[0] !== undefined && this.files[0] !== null) {
        document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = "Type is " + this.files[0].type.toString();        
    } else {
        throw "Error"
    }
});
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

1) Updated question to reflect that the issue has been observed on Windows 8.1 Firefox. Chrome has a mime type for tar files, but not rar files.

2) Added jQuery to the Fiddle

Comment: You didn't add jQuery to your fiddle. Confirmed not to be working with tar files.

Comment: What operating system are you on? It might be that the browser is delegating to the operating system to resolve the mime type, or there is no association in the browser configuration between that file extension and its mime type. Trying configuring your browser to know which external program should open a .tar or .rar. Maybe that will help?

Comment: It's ok for rar and tar, it returns : Type is application/x-rar (or x-tar) on MacOs/Chrome. On which OS / browser are you testing it ?

Comment: I added a tar file created with tar cvf whatever.tar file.jpg and it seemed to fly, listing type as "Type is application/x-tar" and "Type is application/x-rar-compressed" wit command rar a whatever.rar pathe/to/image.jpg. OSX/Chrome.  Can we get update on OS type, browser? I have tested successfully on a single computer, Chrome, Firefox and Safari

Comment: Same on MacOs/Firefox.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

JQuery just wraps the underlying File API used in most browsers, so there is no difference how JQuery and Javascript handle files and mime types. Here is the File API spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-type

The `File` object that you are manipulating inherits the **type** property from the `Blob` object, and the browser uses the blob (byte array) to determine the mime type.

To accomplish that task each browser implements a file sniffing algorithm to "read" the mime type from the byte array, and if the mime type doesn't match, it will return an empty string like in your scenario above.

Here is the full algorithm spec:

https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/

So now you are wondering why it doesn't work for TAR, ZIP and RAR files, and why does it work for some people and not for you?.. because the file sniffing algorithm is evidently not perfect.

It uses **byte pattern matching**, and that seems not reliable enough.

For example i have used WinRaR on my windows 8 box to  compress a file, and the initial bytes of the created file are:

`52 61 72 21 1A 07 00`

However, to recognize it as .RAR the browser byte pattern matching algorithm expects

`52 61 72 20 1A 07 00`

As you see there is a slight difference, and when i uploaded my RAR file to the browser using your code above, Firefox wasn't able to recognize the Mime-Type, and i got an empty string in the type property.

However, when i packed a ZIP file using WinRar on the same machine with default settings it generates an initial byte array sequence of `50 4B 03 04` that matched with the zip byte pattern expected by the algorithm, and when i used your code above it was able to detect the mime type correctly as **application/zip**!

So as you see from my explanation, it is a matter of serialization, and the "imperfection" of the algorithm that matches the serialized bytes with mime extensions in the browsers.

Based on everything mentioned above, i would recommend NOT relying on the mime sniffing, and instead use your custom code to determine the mime type OR existing libraries. You can use a server-side or a client-side approach.

If you want to stick to the client you could use the following JS library:

https://github.com/rsdoiel/mimetype-js

And then discovering the mime type would be a matter of one line of code:

```
mimetype.lookup("myfile.rar")
```

Here is a working Fiddle, upgrading your example to use mimetype js:

http://jsfiddle.net/jd8h7wvs/4/

Comment: Just add if it was not clear: The "mimetype.js" is a simple lookup table. It works based on the extension of the file and search within a catalog the type corresponding.

Comment: Fantastic. This is exactly what I was looking for. The bounty is all yours (and is well deserved if I do say so myself).

Comment: ...in 16 hours (I'll add it to my todo list)